# Differences between Direct3D devices

Tags: directx

A device seems like a kind of hardware device. But there's HAL device and reference device. So **can I understand a D3D device as a system**, a software driver system or a hardware and hardware driver system which is a rendering component of D3D?

Updates：I think a "virtual device" is more appropriate, they share the same physical hardware device.

And for the difference of HAL device and reference device, **can I say that HAL device take advantage of GPU while reference device take advantage of CPU** which is apparently slower. But reference device is useful for feature testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is appropriate for the Stack Overflow community, but:

The D3D device is a standard interface used to interact in a uniform way with either a physical GPU, or to use the CPU to emulate the function if a physical GPU (obviously with a performance cost).

In that respect, it is a "Virtual Device", but it is better to simply think of it as a group of functions that allow interaction with a GPU.

Comment: Does a reference device use a CPU instead of a GPU?

Comment: Yes, it uses the CPU to emulate a GPU, either for feature testing, or if a compatible GPU isn't connected to the computer.